# .net framework version req'd for MS Sync Framework

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

Can anyone tell me what version of the .NET framework (CLR and BCL) is req'd for the recently-released MS Sync Framework (for support of occasionally-connected-applications)?

Its listed as Sync Framework V1 for ADO.NET v2.0 but none of its listed req'ments say anything about the .NET fx version that is required to support it.

Anyone got any experience with this...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sync Services for ADO.NET 2.0 requires ADO.NET 2.0 on the server. Sync Services requires ADO.NET 2.0 for desktop clients or .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 for device clients.

So, you should have .net framework 2.0 or above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it will work with 2.0 and newer.  Remember, 3.5 and 3.0 are still running on the 2.0 CLR.  You get everything you need for Sync within the Sync namespaces, and I think that those are not dependent on any 3.0 or 3.5 language features.

Answer (score 0):

If it specifies ADO.NET 2.0, then you'll need at least .NET 2.0. ADO.NET changed a lot between 1.1 and 2.0